# How to compute a rolling average by rank (not row) in Teradata?

Tags: sql, average, teradata, ansi-sql, rolling-average

I **have** the following table in Teradata:

```
 ranked | data_val 
-------- ----------
 1      | 100
 2      |  30
 2      |  20
 2      |  70
```

I **want** the following table, where `avg_val` is the rolling average of `data_val` values ordered by increasingly ascending `ranked` values:

```
 ranked | avg_val 
------ ---------
 1      | 100
 2      |  55
```

---

I try using:

```
SELECT 
    ranked
  , AVERAGE(data)val) OVER (
      PARTITION BY NULL 
      ORDER BY ranked ASC
      ROWS UNBOUNDED PRECEDING
      ) AS avg_val
  FROM tbl
;
```

but I get this:

```
 ranked | avg_val 
------ ---------
 1      | 100
 2      |  65
 2      |  50
 2      |  55
```

which is not what I want.

How do I return the desired output?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about aggregation with window functions?

```
select ranked,
       (sum(sum(data_val)) over (order by ranked rows between unbounded preceding and current row) /
        sum(count(*)) over (order by ranked rows between unbounded preceding and current row)
       )
from t
group by ranked;
```

Comment: Needs a ROWS UNBOUNDED PRECEDING in there a couple times, but it works.

```select ranked,
       sum(sum(data_val)) over (order by ranked ROWS UNBOUNDED PRECEDING) / sum(count(*)) over (order by ranked ROWS UNBOUNDED PRECEDING)
from tbl
group by ranked;
```

Comment: @Sam . . . Arrgh.  Hasn't Teradata fixed that yet.  I added the windowing clause.

Comment: No worries. I don't have a have enough stack overflow reputation to show the upvote yet, but rest assured, you have been upvoted.

Comment: Not defaulting to `RANGE unbounded preceding` has historical reasons (and `range` is not supported in Teradata), but explixit `ROWS unbounded preceding` is recommended anyway, because of the possible better performance (and a potentially unexpected result for a non-unique order by)

Comment: @dnoeth . . . Oh.  The default should be `range` but Teradata doesn't support that.  So, it requires the windowing clause to express the `rows` construct.  That actually makes some sense.